# Java - use new String( ) or valueOf(char[])

Tags: java

I am upgrading an application from Java 8 to Java 9.
Work was started several years ago by someone no longer with the company.

They replaced uses of  `new Integer(int)` with `Integer.valueOf()`
I understand this has advantages in terms of avoiding unnecessary object, and have read several posts on the subject including [Joshua Bloch on Considering static factory methods instead of constructors](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151)

is there any value to replacing code like
`val x = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "C")`
with

```
String.valueOf(new char[] { 'A' , '\u00ea' , '\u00f1' , '\u00fc' , 'C' })
```

similarly how, if at all would you update

```
new String[]{"alpha", "beta", "plabelColor"};
```

Comment: What has the last line, the string array, got to do with the rest of your question?

Comment: java9 is already outdated and out of support, why not go for at least some supported version like java 11. and `val` keyword isn't even java?

Comment: You could also treat that whole thing as a string literal with `var x = "A\u00ea\u00f1\u00fcC"`

Comment: I'd like to talk to the management about wasting development time on trivial updates that have no effect on the end product.

Comment: indeed, if you've done changes like these for several years, your situation seems really bad.

Comment: Using Integer.valueOf(int) instead of new Integer(int) is a good idea. If I saw new Integer(int) in some code I was working on (without some good reason), I would change it. Using String.valueOf(char[]) instead of new String(char[]) is arbitrary.

Comment: Using `Integer.valueOf(int)` instead of `new Integer(int)` is *often* a good idea, depending on how often the values you are using are small enough to be in the cache. If they rarely are, then the savings you get by sometimes reusing objects from the cache can be less than the cost of always having to check the cache first.

Answer (score 2):

Don't introduce micro optimisations, if you cannot measure the impact AND require the optimisation.

We are talking about tiny micro optimisations here. If your application is not a high frequency trading application, where every nano second matters, you should favour readability of the code over micro optimisations. These optimisations might even result in the same code after compiling (or realeasing a newer compiler optimisation). These kind of optimisations hardly have any influence on your users measurable response time.

If you want to measure the impact, I suggest you use [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for it.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `new Integer(int)` with `Integer.valueOf(int)` is (more than just) a good idea - `new Integer(int)` has been deprecated (Java 9) and marked for removal (Java 16).

`val x = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "C")` is **not** really Java; if Java, I would recommend `var x = "A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "C"` or even `var x = "A\u00ea\u00f1\u00fcC"` (unless a new, not-interned String is required (no idea why))

`new String[]{"alpha", "beta", "plabelColor"}` - no update needed

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no reason to replace `new String(char[])` with `String.valueOf(char[])`, and in fact the latter is likely implemented by just doing the former - here's the source code of the `String` class from JDK 9, for example ([link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/d966fc5a7be5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2812)):

```java
    public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
        return new String(data);
    }
```

So the only difference would be one extra method call (which at best would be inlined by the JIT). On the other hand, if there is a difference then it would be extremely small, and not worth considering, so instead of thinking about performance you should probably choose based on which way you think is more readable.

That said, the code in your example is not using the `new String(char[])` constructor, it is using the `new String(String)` constructor to copy a string. This is not needed, you can just write the expression which creates the string without calling the constructor, unless there is some reason your code requires the string object to not be interned (and if it does, that smells like a bad design to me.)

---

If you do think there might be some benefit in caching frequently-used strings, you should implement a cache yourself, design it to be optimised for the kind of strings your application is likely to be dealing with, and then benchmark it to see if it's actually faster. You'll have the cost of checking the cache *every* time, and this cost will likely be larger for strings than for integers, especially if it involves hashing and testing equality of strings; so if there are too many cache misses then the net effect would be negative. The cache miss rate will be highly dependent on your application, so you do want to benchmark with realistic data.